# getting codelite working with git

Tags: git, bitbucket, codelite

i am trying to set up codelite to work with git using [this](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/GitPlugin) tutorial
i created a repo in bitbucket,
using SourceTree, i cloned the repo and made a few commit to make sure its working.

then i created a new project in codeLite with the Repo folder as the project folder,

i selected the folder with "set git repository path"

then i made a commit and tried pushing it ("push local changes"),
the problem is i get this window [image: this]

the process doesn't end and the changes aren't reflected in bitBucket

do i need to enter credentials somewhere in codeLite (i only entered them in SourceTree so far)

how do i make the push command work?

Answer (score 0):

You failed to mention your OS and your codelite version, so I will assume Windows here.

You should try to use a more recent version of CodeLite (IIRC, I removed this window since 2 versions at least)

The current version of CodeLite is 7.0 (for Windows/OSX there are also 7.1 weekly build)

Eran